# how to debug plus client(google+) "internal error" toast in android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I saw earlier posts on stackoverflow regarding this but from the answers I concluded they do not apply to my case.

I'm getting this "an internal error has occurred" toast when I click on sign in button. How do I find out whats wrong? thanks.

Comment: put a break point in the first statement of listner, and debug it step by step

Comment: check ```adb logcat```, there are also additional messages from google play services

Comment: thanks, I checked but saw nothing in the logcat. I ran the official google+ example app hidden somewhere in the sdk folders and that was giving me the same toast. Any other idea except than starting it all over again?

Answer (score 2):

That happend to me today, you need to create a "Client ID" in Google Api acces pane

Official tutorial:  [Click here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I just started the entire process from scratch and its working now. Would have loved to know what the problem was actually if anyone knows. Thanks.

Comment: hi NewOverHere  can i ask sample apk of you app, i have the same problem with you, i have been searching alot but there is no progress. i want to see a working one. im using android studio.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding debug with the command:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
```

Answer (score -1):

Once goto delete that file .android/debug.keystore after restart ur eclipse. new key is there on Window -> Prefernces -> Android -> sha1 key u just copy that and add new project in ur console page and paste ur new key and package name. after try its working...